# Python TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql

Код функции:

```
def create_poll(connection, title, owner, options):
    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(INSERT_POLL_RETURN_ID, (title, owner))
            #cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM polls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;")

            poll_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            option_values = [(option_text, poll_id) for option_text in options]

            execute_values(cursor, INSERT_OPTION, option_values)
            for option_value in option_values:
                cursor.execute(INSERT_OPTION, option_value)
```

Логи:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\app.py", line 103, in <module>
    menu()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\app.py", line 98, in menu
    MENU_OPTIONS[selection](connection)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\app.py", line 30, in prompt_create_poll
    database.create_poll(connection, poll_title, poll_owner, options)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\database.py", line 88, in create_poll
    cursor.execute(INSERT_OPTION, option_value)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: что у вас в INSERT_OPTION и option_value?

Comment: INSERT_OPTION = "INSERT INTO options (option_text, poll_id) VALUES %s;"

option_values = [(option_text, poll_id) for option_text in options]

Comment: в option_value - кортеж из двух элементов, а в INSERT_OPTION - только одна %s... не из-за этого ли?

Comment: Сделать так (%s, %s) ?

Comment: Получил в результате такую ошибку:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\app.py", line 103, in <module>
    menu()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\app
    execute_values(cursor, INSERT_OPTION, option_values)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extras.py", line 1281, in execute_values
    pre, post = _split_sql(sql)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extras.py", line 1317, in _split_sql
    raise ValueError(   
 
ValueError: the query contains more than one '%s' placeholder